# Django: Fetching data from an open source API

Tags: json, django, database, fetch-api

I am trying to fetch public holiday data for France, Australia and Germany from https://date.nager.at/ with the documentation at https://date.nager.at/swagger/index.html and store it in a JSON file.

Until now, I have created an endpoint /fetch_and_save with its own URL, but only managed to write dummy data in the views.py file. How do I fetch the data above and store it in a database through Django?

Edit: I have been asked to show the code.
I ran

```
python3 manage.py startapp fetch_and_save
```

to create the fetching application, and I have the following URL patterns in storefront/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('fetch_and_save/', include('fetch_and_save.urls')),
]
```

then I added function in fetch_and_save/views.py:

```
def say_hello(request):
    return HttpResponse('Fetch the data from date.nager.at here')
```

and I called that in fetch_and_save/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.say_hello)
]
```

That's it. It's just a hello world app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have some clues, how to do that in simple way:

`fetch_and_save/views.py`

```
import json
import requests


def get_public_holidays(request, year, tag):
    response = requests.get(f'https://date.nager.at/api/v2/PublicHolidays/{year}/{tag}')
    with open(f'public_holidays_{tag}_{year}.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(response.text, outfile)
    ...
```

`fetch_and_save/urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:year>/<str:tag>/', views.get_public_holidays)
]
```

Then if you add i.e. `/2020/DE` you will fetch the public holidays 2020 of Germany and save it to the json file with a name `public_holidays_DE_2020.json`.